# R Time series - append column with 1 or 0 depending on future result

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the .csv data below with thousands of rows, and want to append to the end of the csv in R, if one column is over a specified number over a duration of time. For example, column usdjpy will be over .005 in 20 minutes, it would append a 1 to the end (new column), if not it would be 0.

First column is time, and the rest are variables.

```
> attributes(dde)
$class
[1] "data.frame"

> head(dde)
            time  usdjpy  eurjpy  gbpjpy audjpy cadjpy  chfjpy nzdjpy  eurusd
1 9/7/2014 21:20 105.061 136.099 169.961 98.391 96.515 112.802 87.277 1.29531
2 9/7/2014 21:26 105.068 136.074 169.954 98.399 96.521 112.790 87.276 1.29503
3 9/7/2014 21:31 105.078 136.107 170.031 98.414 96.528 112.813 87.287 1.29514
4 9/7/2014 21:35 105.068 136.102 170.001 98.424 96.516 112.789 87.289 1.29520
5 9/7/2014 21:41 105.074 136.109 169.994 98.422 96.519 112.821 87.300 1.29517
6 9/7/2014 21:45 105.091 136.114 170.028 98.420 96.539 112.829 87.302 1.29519
```

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, not images, so users can use it for their answers. You can paste the output from `dput(head(dde))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DT <- dde(A=1:5, B=1:5*10, C=1:5*100)
>   DT